# closed form solution for Affine transformation between 2 sets of 3 colinear points with a vector attached to each

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, rotations, nonlinear-system, rigid-transformation

I want to estimate the scale, rotation and translation between two sets of 3 colinear 3D points. Each 3D point has a direction information (A unit vector attached to it).  In case we don't have this direction information, there would be infinite solutions. But in this case there has to be a unique solution (my intuition) . I am not sure how to solve this. Please suggest me how to approach this problem.

[image: rigid transformation with scale]

Comment: The corresponding segment lengths must be proportional (or nearly so within your error tolerance) for there to even be such an affine transformation.

Comment: Actually, the points on the right were obtained by affine transformation of points on the left. So I know that an affine transformation exist. But I need to estimate the transformation.

Comment: It should be obvious how to get the scale factor and translation. If that middle point isn’t the midpoint of the segment, you can use it to disambiguate. There’s an infinite number of rotations possible, but the ones with max/min angle are quite easy to find.

Comment: Could you please help me understand what the line "the ones with max/min angle are quite easy to find" ?